# How to change the font in grid areas

Tags: angular

I forked an angular stackblitz and modified the grid. How may I change the font to have different fonts for each grid area?  This is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sse4n5)

Here is the component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

export interface Tile {
  color: string;
  cols: number;
  rows: number;
  text: string;
}

/   **
 * @title Dynamic grid-list
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'grid-list-dynamic-example',
  templateUrl: 'grid-list-dynamic-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['grid-list-dynamic-example.css'],
})
export class GridListDynamicExample {
  tiles: Tile[] = [
    {text: '', cols: 5, rows: 1, color: 'lightblue'},
    {text: 'Two', cols: 3, rows: 1, color: 'lightgreen'},
    {text: 'Three', cols: 2, rows: 2, color: 'lightpink'},
    {text: 'Four', cols: 3, rows: 1, color: '#DDBDF1'},
    {text: 'Five', cols: 3, rows: 1, color: '#DDBDF1'},
      {text: 'Six', cols: 2, rows: 1, color: '#DDBDF1'},
  ];
}
```

This is the html file:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="5" rowHeight="20vh" [gutterSize]="'0px'">
   <mat-grid-tile
      *ngFor="let tile of tiles"
      [colspan]="tile.cols"
      [rowspan]="tile.rows"
      [style.background]="tile.color">
    {{tile.text}}
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: Are you looking for this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sse4n5-zhvm3t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an index to change the font-size dynamically (But I don't think this will help you), so have provided two solutions:

> Solution 1:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="5" rowHeight="20vh" [gutterSize]="'0px'">
  <mat-grid-tile
      *ngFor="let tile of tiles; let i = index"
      [colspan]="tile.cols"
      [rowspan]="tile.rows"
      [style.background]="tile.color"
      [ngStyle]="{'font-size': i * 10 + 'px'}">
    {{tile.text}}
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

> Solution 2:

You can add another parameter in the data itself as `size`:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="5" rowHeight="20vh" [gutterSize]="'0px'">
  <mat-grid-tile
      *ngFor="let tile of tiles; let i = index"
      [colspan]="tile.cols"
      [rowspan]="tile.rows"
      [style.background]="tile.color"
      [ngStyle]="{'font-size': tile.size + 'px'}">
    {{tile.text}}
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

TS code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export interface Tile {
  color: string;
  cols: number;
  rows: number;
  text: string;
  size: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'grid-list-dynamic-example',
  templateUrl: 'grid-list-dynamic-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['grid-list-dynamic-example.css'],
})
export class GridListDynamicExample {
  tiles: Tile[] = [
    { text: 'One', cols: 5, rows: 1, color: 'lightblue', size: '15' },
    { text: 'Two', cols: 3, rows: 1, color: 'lightgreen', size: '20' },
    { text: 'Three', cols: 2, rows: 2, color: 'lightpink', size: '25' },
    { text: 'Four', cols: 3, rows: 1, color: '#DDBDF1', size: '30' },
    { text: 'Five', cols: 3, rows: 1, color: '#DDBDF1', size: '35' },
    { text: 'Six', cols: 2, rows: 1, color: '#DDBDF1', size: '40' },
  ];
}
```

[`StackBlitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sse4n5-zhvm3t)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[ngStyle]="{'font-family': tile.font}"` inside the `mat-grid-tile` tag.

You can then add a property `font` and remove the `Tile[]`:

```
  tiles = [
    {text: '', cols: 5, rows: 1, color: 'lightblue',size:'15', font: 'verdana'},
    {text: 'Two', cols: 3, rows: 1, color: 'lightgreen',size:'20', font: 'serif'},
    {text: 'Three', cols: 2, rows: 2, color: 'lightpink',size:'25', font: 'cortana'},
    {text: 'Four', cols: 3, rows: 1, color: '#DDBDF1',size:'30', font: 'arial'},
    {text: 'Five', cols: 3, rows: 1, color: '#DDBDF1',size:'35', font: 'comic'},
    {text: 'Six', cols: 2, rows: 1, color: '#DDBDF1',size:'40', font: 'courier'},
  ];
}
```

Comment: That would change all of the grid areas to the same font.  I am looking to have a different font for each grid area.